# Vue.js testing with JSDOM

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jsdom

I have a Vue.js-based project, generated with [Vue-webpack-simple](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple) template. It uses `.vue` files to define components, so I can't import them in Node.js as it is.

Then I am trying to set up the test environment with JSDOM. How can I load and process `.vue` files there?

I have an idea that I can use Webpack with [`vue-loader`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader) somehow, but I am stuck with setting this up. Could you also recommend an example for similar setup?